# How to read binary file from data dir in main.js of firefox addon

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I have a problem in developing firefox addon. I have a binary file in standard data/ dir. How can I get its contents (byte string) in main.js? I've tried a lot but no success. Thank you.

Well finally I got some progress:

```
var url = self.data.url("img.png")
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', url, false);
xhr.overrideMimeType("application/octet-stream")
xhr.send();
console.log(xhr.response.lenght) //4325
```

But lenght != img.png! Why?
Actually img.png size = 4552 bytes...

Comment: I think you set `xhr.responseType='arraybuffer'` and that should give you an array buffer with binary data. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25492225/how-to-download-image-to-desktop-with-os-file

Comment: Thank you, responseType solves the problem (also switched to async request).

Comment: Nice @user3070377 async is the way to go

Comment: So as this is resolved can you please share your solution and accept it.