# Download and save file inside my extension folder in Firefox?

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, browser-addons, firefox-addon-restartless

I would like to do the following from my firefox addon:

a). Determine my addons folder location.

b). Prompt the user to initiate a download.

c). Download and save the download

All the code examples available are for older API's and I have no clue on how to get them working for recent [E10 (multi-process)](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Electrolysis) code changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### A - Get addons folder location

```
var OSPath_addons = Services.dirsvc.get('XREUSysExt', Ci.nsIFile).path
```

### B - Trigger download with path with no user notification

[How to download image to desktop with OS.File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25492225/how-to-download-image-to-desktop-with-os-file)

#### With user notification:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Downloads.jsm#createDownload%28%29

Comment: Great, how to initiate this from a "content script"? The addon has bootstrap.js, overlay.js and content.js.

Comment: @Stacked Do `var {Cc, Cu, Ci} = require('chrome')` then you can access all that `Cu` stuff. Start by importnat Services.jsm: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Services.jsm?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript_code_modules%2FServices.jsm

Comment: I meant to access/initiate the download from a user-script (loaded for a particular website only) after prompting the user to get the optional download in a injected iframe inside the webpage, I am sure `CU` won't work from there. I wanted to know how to call the function to start the download from the content-script?

Comment: @Stacked you have to port.emit to you main.js script and he iwll have to do the download. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/using_port#port.emit%28%29