# Downloading a file from my mozilla addon sent by the server

Tags: download, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, mozilla, browser-addons

I am developing a amozilla addon , and I have to download a file that is stored in the server. I would retrieve the file from the server using xmlHttpRequest. My question is how I download the response file in my browser from my mozilla addon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use xmlHttpRequest with requestType of arrayBuffer, then use OS.File to write that to file: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25492679/1828637

This way does not show in the download manager, if you want it to show in the manager then you should use Downloads.jsm module: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Downloads.jsm

Comment: Solution in the post http://stackoverflow.com/a/25492679/1828637 suits me , but the directory where the file has to be stored must be decided by the user. i.e. A **Save As** box must prompt for the download directory. How could I achieve this from your solution?

Comment: @muthu: use nsIFilePicker with `modeGetFolder`: https://github.com/Noitidart/Icon-Container-Generator/blob/c196fb5db9eb41b5478f898658b8db175c99920f/resources/scripts/app.js#L250-L259