# Store and use images locally

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm quite new to addons development on Firefox.

I need to store an image from a given url, and then get the path to upload on another web. I read the Mozilla docs but can't figure how to do this.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

This does exactly what you need: [How to download image to desktop with OS.File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25492225/how-to-download-image-to-desktop-with-os-file/) - you download the image with XHR, you then write that data to anywhere you want with `OS.File.writeAtomic` Instead of that XHR function, because you are using the SDK you should use the request module - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/request